# The event is never used

Tags: c#, events

I'm having a problem with writing a plugin for some kind of software, with an event handler more specifically. What I get is a warning:

> The event 'TestPlugin.LogChanged' is never used

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FUTMate.PluginFunctions;
using FUTMate.controllers;


namespace TestPlugin
{

public delegate void LogChangedEventHandler(Object source, string log);

public partial class TestPlugin : Form
{
    public event LogChangedEventHandler LogChanged;



    public TestPlugin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LogChanged += new LogChangedEventHandler(HandleLogChanged);

        MessageBox.Show("Test");

    }

    void HandleLogChanged(Object source, string log)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test: " + log);
    }

}
}
```

Any ideas what could be done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It means although the event is _registered_, it is never "fired", and the event handler has no chance to be called.

Comment: Listening to your own event is never very sensible.  Events exist for the benefit of external code, the kind you don't know about.  Since you never fire the event, your HandleLogChanged() method will never be called.  This surely requires a re-think.